# Cython "Unknown type in template argument" error

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to create the Python wrapper for following C++ class.

```
A(vector<pair<double, double>>* points, double r_cutoff) 
void func(vector<pair<double, double>>* offset)
```

To Python wrapper gets the Numpy's ndarray as an argument and create a vector from it. Then, it tries to pass the address to the C++ constructor and its function "func".

```
cdef extern from "cell.h" namespace "cl":
    cdef cppclass A:
        A(vector[pair[double, double]]* points, double r_cutoff) except +
        void func(vector[pair[double, double]]* offset)

cdef class PyA:
    cdef A* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, np.ndarray points, double r_cutoff):
        cdef vector[pair[double, double]] vec
        vec.resize(points.shape[0])
        for i in range(points.shape[0]):
            vec[i].first = points[i][0]
            vec[i].second = points[i][1]

        self.thisptr = new A(&vec, r_cutoff)

    def func(self, np.ndarray offset):
        cdef vector[pair[double, double]] vec
        vec.resize(offset.shape[0])

        for i in range(offset.shape[0]):
            vec[i].first = offset[i][0]
            vec[i].second = offset[i][1]
        self.thisptr.func(&vec)
```

But it complains that there is an unknown type in

```
  def func(self, np.ndarray offset):
        cdef vector[pair[double, double]] vec
                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

file.pyx:27:25: unknown type in template argument
```

I correctly imported both vector and pair but I don't understand why Cython is complaining about this. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cimport the definitions of `vector` and `pair`, so Cython knows them, i.e.:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.utility cimport pair
....
```

Comment: you are genious.